# Sexual Relations with a married woman that's asur to her husband

Tags: marriage, sexuality, divorce, karet

Is it ok for a man to have relations with a married woman who's already been unfaithful to her husband?
Is there still an isur kareth?
Or since she's already prohibited from being with her husband and requires a divorce, the isur of kareth doesn't apply?

Comment: It would not make a difference. She is still a married woman.

Comment: An excellent question! Some forbidden relationships prevent an initial marriage from taking place. So a brother-sister are never married, even if they had a ceremony. But what about a woman-severed penis man? Im not sure

Comment: Totally irrelevant, he would still be *chayav misah*.